# Why trigger is not schema-scoped?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, oracle

Why trigger is not schema-scoped object? I need some technical answer.

This query did't return the count of trigger.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.objects
```

This return the count of trigger.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.triggers
```

Comment: please speficy RDBMS ,, oracle or mysql ? I guess mysql right ?

Comment: Its in mssql. but,i wonder to know same case in other RDBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft SQL Server has both DML triggers and DDL triggers.  DML triggers are schema-scoped with the schema determined by the parent object (table or view).  DDL triggers are not schema-scoped and therefore are not returned by the sys.objects catalog view.

Answer (score 0):

Some triggers can be system ones.
You can create AFTER STARTUP ON DATABASE triggers in Oracle i.e.